# Azure Blob Storage Spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to connect Spark to azure blob storage (**wasbs**).
I add the following jars in the hadoop classpath

```
com.microsoft.azure_azure-storage-7.0.0.jar
org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-annotations-3.1.2.jar
org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-auth-3.1.2.jar
org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-azure-3.1.2.jar
org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-http-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-io-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-security-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-server-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-servlet-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-webapp-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
org.eclipse.jetty_jetty-xml-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
```

and i try to use spark-submit using:

```
spark-submit --class mainClass --jars jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-azure-3.1.2.jar,jars/com.microsoft.azure_azure-storage-7.0.0.jar,jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar myjar.jar
```

and i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/JSON$Convertor
```

If i remove **hadoop-commons** from the spark-submit --jars i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities
```

and if i add --jars jars/* to include all the jar files along with the jetty-utils i get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MainClass
```

i saw similar posts that indicate multiple versions of jetty, but i can't find other versions anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For the first exception, you're missing jetty util

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/9.3.24.v20180605

And you should verify `hadoop classpath` returns what you want

For the remaining exceptions, you should verify that you can run `hadoop fs - ls wasb://path` on each potential Spark executor

Comment: I worked around this using hadoop-azure_2.7.1 depedency and even though i had some issues again, it seems that for some reason it had something to do with delta lake. When i use read.format("delta") i was getting a Wasbs class not found.. when i changed to read.format("parquet") everything work correctly, but i have no idea why

Comment: Parquet is natively built in. Delta is an external package, right?

Comment: Yes, it needed some additional configurations described here:
https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html
Now the thing is that they recommend hadoop-azure_2.9.1+ jar. I use 2.7.1 which excludes delta lakes acid properties, although it works. If i add jar 2.9.1 i get ClassNotFound StreamCapabilities, which comes with hadoop-commons, but if i add hadoop-commons i get an exception for conflict classes

Comment: Well, yeah, sounds like you need to upgrade Hadoop

Comment: for the first error, jetty-util-ajax worked for me instead of jetty-util. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util-ajax/9.3.24.v20180605